# How to redefine the hook in XY-pic?

Tags: xy-pic, xymatrix

I want to add an empty space before the hooked arrow the way it is done in the `barr` package.

```
\newdir{ (}{{ }*!/-.5em/@^{(}}%
```

But instead of defining a new `\dir{ (}`, I just want to redefine `\dir{(}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\let\varahook\ahook
\newdir^{(}{{ }*!/-.5em/\varahook}

\begin{document}

$$\xymatrix{A \ar@{^{(}->}[r] & B}$$

\end{document}
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Why not go all out and switch to `tikz-cd` the hook arrow there looks much nicer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.